# Updating Pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have `services` and `items` table. i have the pivot table as `service_item`.  I am able to store data into my pivot table however i can't get the right syntax to update the pivot table. My code stores a new data when i try to update an existing data.

**PS**: My code although is able to edit the client's name but not the items that the client bought earlier.

I want to be able to update the item_id and quantity

**service_item** - pivot.

```
service_id

item_id

qty
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $service = new Service(array(
         'id' => $service_no,

     ));

     $service->save();
     $selectedItems = [];         
    foreach($request->get('item_id') as $key => $id) {
        $selectedItems[$id] = ['qty' => $request->get('quantity')[$key]];
    }  
     $service->items()->attach($selectedItems);  
 }



 public function update($id, Request $request)
     {
         $service = Service::findOrFail($id);
         $service->clients->name = $request->get('name');   
         $service->clients->save();

         $selectedItems = [];         
         foreach($request->get('item_id') as $key => $id) {
             $selectedItems[$id] = ['qty' => $request->get('quantity')[$key]];
         }  
          $service->items()->attach($selectedItems);  


     }
```

Comment: Probably I don't understood correctly but who is  $service_no from    $service = new Service(array(
         'id' => $service_no,

Comment: @Radu, i don't have issues with that ( storing service into my database). Now the `$service_no` is the id of the service i am creating which i generate using an algorithm into the variable `$service_no`. I didn't include the algorithm but that works

Comment: I think the problem is in the foreign keys. Especially in service_id foreign in pivot table. Check, are you using right service for updating?

Comment: @LearnLaravel Thank you, please see if this tutorial helps: [pivotTable-laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/30)

Comment: I believe, each separated application, should have exactly the same columns names in every pivot, it would contain. I always have `related_id` and `entry_id` for any relation.

Comment: @VaheShak, i am using the right service. I console.log and it is the right service? is my syntax correct to update?

Comment: My syntax is what i am concerned about because my `service` is correct but then it doesn't update the existing one but instead , it create/attach a new item to the existing one

Answer (score 1):

Okay after researching, i was able to solve this using `updateExistingPivot`

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
     {
         $service = Service::findOrFail($id);
         $service->clients->name = $request->get('name');   
         $service->clients->save();

         $selectedItems = [];         
         foreach($request->get('item_id') as $key => $id) {
             $selectedItems[$id] = ['qty' => $request->get('quantity')[$key]];
         }  
         $service->items()->updateExistingPivot($item_id, ['quantity' => selectedItems], false);


     }
```